# Issue in cordova platform add android in window

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

This is my issue :

> cordova platform add android --save
>   Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.3.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

[ERROR] Exception:
My ionic info is:
  @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : none
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.2.4
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.9.1
npm               : 5.5.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Anusha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: try to add the cordova-android lower version like cordova platform add android@6.0.0 --save

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Cordova android platform versions supported by the MobileFirst plug-ins, is: cordova-android: >= 6.1.2 and < 7.0

Try using command '`cordova platform add android@6.1.2`'.

For more details see here : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/